# what is wrong in my code for uploading image using ajax php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a profile settings page on which users can change their profile info, picture etc. Writing code for changing info wasn't difficult but for image change I am using ajax php plugin I found on a site. Now this plugin has two pages one php code for storing image into database and ajax page with form to dynamically upload image. The ajax code and form are on my setting.php page which also has some other javascript and php validations. Now on this page javascript validations for profile info is causing me trouble, no image is uploaded when I try to change image but when I remove javascript validation code image upload plugin works fine. Can someone explain what is problem here and how to solve it?

settings.php

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', '#image_upload_file', function () {
var progressBar = $('.progressBar'), bar = $('.progressBar .bar'), percent = $('.progressBar .percent');

$('#image_upload_form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    progressBar.fadeIn();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
success: function(html, statusText, xhr, $form) {       
    obj = $.parseJSON(html);    
    if(obj.status){     
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
        $("#imgArea>img").prop('src',obj.image_medium);         
    }else{
        alert(obj.error);
    }
},
complete: function(xhr) {
    progressBar.fadeOut();          
}   
}).submit();        

});
</script>
```

one of the javascript codes that validate profile info on settings page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#emailup').click(function() {
      var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
      var filter=/^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;      
            if (!filter.test(email) || email == "") {
                $('#err').html('Enter a valid email');
                return false;
            }
            else if (email.length > 255) {
                $('#err').html('Enter a valid email');
                return false;
            }
           });
        });
  </script>
```

phpcode.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image_upload_file'])){
$output['status']=FALSE;
set_time_limit(0);
$allowedImageType = array("image/gif",   "image/jpeg",   "image/pjpeg",   "image/png",   "image/x-png"  );

if ($_FILES['image_upload_file']["error"] > 0) {
    $output['error']= "Error in File";
}
elseif (!in_array($_FILES['image_upload_file']["type"], $allowedImageType)) {
    $output['error']= "You can only upload JPG, PNG and GIF file";
}
elseif (round($_FILES['image_upload_file']["size"] / 1024) > 4096) {
    $output['error']= "You can upload file size up to 4 MB";
} else {
    /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - start*/
    createDir(IMAGE_SMALL_DIR);
    createDir(IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR);
    /*create directory with 777 permission if not exist - end*/
    $path[0] = $_FILES['image_upload_file']['tmp_name'];
    $file = pathinfo($_FILES['image_upload_file']['name']);
    $fileType = $file["extension"];
    $desiredExt='jpg';
    $fileNameNew = rand(333, 999) . time() . ".$desiredExt";
    $path[1] = IMAGE_MEDIUM_DIR . $fileNameNew;
    $path[2] = IMAGE_SMALL_DIR . $fileNameNew;

    if (createThumb($path[0], $path[1], $fileType, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE, IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE,IMAGE_MEDIUM_SIZE)) {

        if (createThumb($path[1], $path[2],"$desiredExt", IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE, IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE,IMAGE_SMALL_SIZE)) {
            $output['status']=TRUE;
            $output['image_medium']= $path[1];
            $output['image_small']= $path[2];
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($output);
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you get some new js error when adding validation code ?

Comment: @Armen no error just upload image does not work while javascript validation code is there

Comment: Is this the whole validation function? If it is, you should probably return `true` from the function if it validates.

Comment: @jeroen validation code is long so didn't posted here it's just piece of that. problem ain't in validation code it works well but some how it stops image upload javascript  from uploading image.